# What does a semicolon after for-loop means? Why is there a j++ in first loop statement?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I need to implement my own version of Dijkstra algorithm based on priority queues, and while searching some sites about it, I saw an algorithm that actually works but with strange for-loop statements:

```cpp
int i,j,n;
cin >> n;   //number of vertexes
bool *QS = new bool [n];

//whole QS is set to false here

for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(j = 0; QS[j]; j++);
    for(u = j++; j < n; j++)
        if(!QS[j] && (d[j] < d[u]))   //d[i] is table of distances
            u = j;
    QS[u] = true;

    //some code
}
```

I know that `;` after loop means it's empty statement, but if I comment second `for-loop` this program stops working, so it actually means something. I believe that this `u = j++` was meant to be like start form `u = j+1`, but I'm not so sure.

Comment: Post a link to the site. That first for-loop doesn't do anything.

Comment: after the empty loop `j` will point to the first index of `QS` that is false.

Comment: @fdan No, it won't because the array pointed to by QS is never initialised, and so we have UB.

Comment: @NeilButterworth there is a comment that says "whole QS is set to false here"

Comment: https://eduinf.waw.pl/inf/alg/001_search/0138.php
It's in polish so I don't think it would be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for(j = 0; QS[j]; j++);` is used as `j=0; while(QS[j])j++;`

i.e. to find the first j that `QS[j]` is false

Answer (score 1):

```
for(j = 0; QS[j]; j++);
```

sets `j` to 0 and then increments `j` until the first element in `QS` that is false.  You then use that value for the initial value of the third loop.

It is a cleaver way to write it but you can be a lot more expressive on what it is doing using `std::find` and `std::distance` like

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int j = std::distance(std::begin(QS), std::find(std::begin(QS), std::end(QS), false));
    for(u = j++; j < n; j++)
        if(!QS[j] && (d[j] < d[u]))   //d[i] is table of distances
            u = j;
    QS[u] = true;

    //some code
}
```

which explicitly states that `j` will be the distance from the beginning of the array to the first false element.

Answer (score 0):

the second for loop walks through all of the array QS which is an 
array of booleans.  Which will break when one is false, saving the current value of j and starting the next loop with that value +1.